# Is there a really easy way to detect swipes for an imageview?

Tags: android

Possible related question:[Adding Fling Gesture to an image view - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098198/adding-fling-gesture-to-an-image-view-android)

This is what I want:

An imageview-menu, single view, one image shown at a time, when swipe up or down, change the picture accordingly thus enabling users to access different functions.

This is what I plan to do:

Use guesture dector, combining with ontouch event, to detect the down/initial finger contact position then the up/last finger contact position, do a simple math, and figure out if the user had swiped up or down, and execute relevant events accordingly.

This is the problem:

I failed to find a simpler solution and I cannot believe android actually don't have a swipe up/down/left/right event for views, not even imageview.

My questions are:

1. Will my plan work?
2. Is it the optimal/easiest solution, am I overcomplicating things, as in, there absolutely is a dedicated mechanism built in android tot listen to swipes?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45054908/how-to-add-a-gesture-detector-to-a-view-in-android

Comment: 1) yes 2) don't know for very last APIs but no you had to implement it (very easy and lot of example on the web).

Answer (score 0):

Use Touch listener . Take the coordinates of the touch down and up.

check whether swipe up,down,left right from the touch listener using coordinates using simple math function.

Answer (score 0):

There's a gesture detector in Android, and the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13162386/next-and-previous-image-by-swipe-s.) gives an example on how to use it with flinging up and down on a view.

And to answer the question "Is there a really easy way?". Not really, but you you can use [this](https://github.com/pwittchen/swipe). Good luck!